# Nested if statements vs pattern matching in F#

Tags: c#, f#, pattern-matching

I have a function in C# that checks if a student has taken all his exams:

```
public Tuple<bool, string> HasTakenAllExams (string parameters)
{
    // get the collection from db based on built query

    if (parameters.Contains("FullTime"))
    {
        if (collection.English == null) { return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "Value of English is null"); }
        if (collection.Maths == null) { return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "Value of Maths is null"); }
        if (collection.PE == null) { return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "Value of PE is null"); }
    }
    if (collection.Biology == null) { return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "Value of Biology is null"); }

    return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, null);
}
```

I re-wrote it in F# to look like that:

```ml
let HasTakenAllExams parameters : (bool * string) =
    // get the collection from db based on built query
    let mutable someStringMessage = ""
    let mutable someBooleanValue = true
    if (parameters:string).Contains("FullTime") then
        if collection.English == null then someStringMessage <- "Value of English is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
        if collection.Maths == null then someStringMessage <- "Value of Maths is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
        if collection.PE == null then someStringMessage <- "Value of PE is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
    if collection.Biology == null then someStringMessage <- "Value of Biology is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
    (someBooleanValue, someStringMessage)
```

I am guessing that nested if statements are not "best practice" in functional programming and pattern matching is the way to go?

```ml
if (parameters:string).Contains("FullTime") then
    match collection.English with
    | null -> someStringMessage <- "Value of English is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
    match collection.Maths with
    | null -> someStringMessage <- "Value of Maths is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
    match collection.PE with
    | null -> someStringMessage <- "Value of PE is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
else
    match collection.Biology with
    | null -> someStringMessage <- "Value of Biology is null"; someBooleanValue <- false
```

Is there any better/more efficient way to write the code above?

Comment: Is it possible in your function that for example both `collection.English` and `collection.Maths` would be `null`? It seems in this case your code will return an error only for English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write pattern matching equivalent of your C# function like this (I abbreviated `parameters` and `collection`):

```ml
let hasTookExams (prams: string) = 
    match prams.Contains("FullTime"), coll.English, coll.Maths, coll.PE, coll.Biology with
    | true, null, _, _, _ -> (false, "Value of English is null")
    | true, _, null, _, _ -> (false, "Value of Maths is null")
    | true, _, _, null, _ -> (false, "Value of PE is null")
    | _,    _, _, _, null -> (false, "Value of Biology is null") 
    | _                   -> (true, null)
```

Comment: Is pattern matching always a better choice when you could do a simple if else statement in F# ?

Comment: It's not always better choice. In simple cases `if..then..else` better and shorter: `if v = 42 then bla else blabla`

Comment: ``let test1 = function 42 -> "bla" | _ -> "blabla"`` is the same length as
``let test2 v = if v = 42 then "bla" else "blabla"``